# Select rows with highest value from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains some information about users. There is a column for user, column for type, and column for count, like this:

```
name         type     count
robert       x        123
robert       y        456
robert       z        5123
charlie      x        442123
charlie      y        0 
charlie      z        42
```

I'm trying to figure out which type has the highest count per name, so for this case, I would want to select this:

```
name         type    count
robert       z       5123
charlie      x       442123
```

I know I can do something like this to get the max count per name, but I'm not sure how I can include the "type" column, which is actually the most important

```
df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name').sort_index()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you run your code `df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name').sort_index()
` this output what your expected

Comment: your code outputs what you expect as pointed out by wen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you have two maxes for a name with different types:

```
print(df)

      name type   count
0   robert    x     123
1   robert    y     456
2   robert    z    5123
3   robert    a    5123
4  charlie    x  442123
5  charlie    y       0
6  charlie    z      42
```

Use boolean indexing:

```
df[df['count'] == df.groupby('name')['count'].transform('max')]
```

Output:

```
      name type   count
2   robert    z    5123
3   robert    a    5123
4  charlie    x  442123
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name')['count'].idxmax()]['type']
```

```
      name type   count
3  charlie    x  442123
2   robert    z    5123
```

In case you want not just a single max value but the top `n` values per group you can do (e.g. `n = 2`)

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name')['count'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]
```

```
      name type   count
3  charlie    x  442123
5  charlie    z      42
2   robert    z    5123
1   robert    y     456
```

Comment: This seems like the more generalizable answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just sort on name and count, group by name and keep first.

```py
df.sort_values(['name', 'count'],ascending=False).groupby(['name']).first().reset_index()
```

will give you:

```
    name type   count
3  charlie    x  442123
2   robert    z    5123
```

Comment: this doesn't work if there are ties between two rows with the same value

Answer (score 0):

(Very slightly) better yet, you can do:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name')['count'].idxmax(),'type']
```