# How to select data after date which is the index of the max value of columns for each group by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
            ts_code      low     high
2021-08-01  881105.TI   1485.0  1629.0
2021-08-01  885452.TI   2216.0  2391.0
2021-08-01  885525.TI   7427.0  8552.0
2021-08-01  885641.TI   621.0   671.0
2021-08-08  881105.TI   1496.0  1623.0
2021-08-08  885452.TI   2297.0  2406.0
2021-08-08  885525.TI   7300.0  7868.0
2021-08-08  885641.TI   668.0   691.0
2021-08-15  881105.TI   1606.0  1776.0
2021-08-15  885452.TI   2352.0  2459.0
2021-08-15  885525.TI   7525.0  8236.0
2021-08-15  885641.TI   685.0   719.0
2021-08-22  881105.TI   1656.0  1804.0
2021-08-22  885452.TI   2329.0  2415.0
2021-08-22  885525.TI   7400.0  8270.0
2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```

The type of index is `datetime64[ns]`.

**Goal**

- select data after date which is the index of max for `high` column for `ts_code` group.

**Expected**

```
             ts_code    low      high
2021-08-22  881105.TI   1656.0  1804.0
2021-08-15  885452.TI   2352.0  2459.0
2021-08-22  885452.TI   2329.0  2415.0
2021-08-01  885525.TI   7427.0  8552.0
2021-08-08  885525.TI   7300.0  7868.0
2021-08-15  885525.TI   7525.0  8236.0
2021-08-22  885525.TI   7400.0  8270.0
2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```

For example, the max date of `881105.TI` is `2021-08-22` and `885525.TI` is `2021-08-01`. The ouput for each `ts_code` is after the related max date.

**Try and ref**

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842287/select-rows-with-highest-value-from-groupby) returns rows with highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `transform` with `idxmax`

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1 = df[df.index >= df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax')]
out = df1[df1.groupby('ts_code').cumcount()<=1]
out
              ts_code     low    high
2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0
2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0
2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0
2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0
2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0
2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```

Comment: great,  but could you mind explaining why using cumcount() and using chain method to get the result?

Comment: @Jack you only need the the max and the value right after it , so cumcount will only count number of row less than 2