# How to using chain method to select data after date which is the index of the max value of columns for each group by pandas?

Tags: pandas

**Problem**: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354637/how-to-select-data-after-date-which-is-the-index-of-the-max-value-of-columns-for)

**Goal**

using pandas chain method to get the output.

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1 = df[df.index >= df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax')]
out = df1[df1.groupby('ts_code').cumcount()<=1]

out
              ts_code     low    high
2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0
2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0
2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0
2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0
2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0
2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `df[df.index >= df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax')]`?

Comment: Or with chain methods: `df.some_other_op().loc[lambda x: x.index >= x.groupby(...)['high'].transform('idxmax')]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Quang pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69358110/13138364#comment122740977_69358110), chaining actually isn't needed here (except to chain [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) if you want to match the expected output from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69354637/13138364)):

- Either use a boolean filter:

  ```
  df[df.index >= df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax')].sort_values('ts_code')

  #               ts_code     low    high
  # 2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0
  # 2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0
  # 2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0
  # 2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0
  # 2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0
  # 2021-08-15  885525.TI  7525.0  8236.0
  # 2021-08-22  885525.TI  7400.0  8270.0
  # 2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
  ```
- Or a [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) callable:

  ```
  (df.sort_values('ts_code')
     .loc[lambda x: x.index >= x.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax')])
  ```

---

#### Convert existing code with [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html)

But if you want to convert the existing code into a chain, [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) the previous operation's output as input for the next operation.

First [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the `maxdate` for each group and [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) the result into a date filter. Then chain [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to match the expected output from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69354637/13138364):

```
(df.assign(maxdate=df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax'))
   .pipe(lambda x: x[x.index >= x.maxdate])
   .drop(columns='maxdate')
   .sort_values('ts_code'))

#               ts_code     low    high
# 2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0
# 2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0
# 2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0
# 2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0
# 2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0
# 2021-08-15  885525.TI  7525.0  8236.0
# 2021-08-22  885525.TI  7400.0  8270.0
# 2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```

I'm not sure why [BENY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354767/13138364) included an extra `cumcount` filter, but you can also [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) that if you want (however I don't think this is what your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69354637/13138364) asks for):

```
(df.assign(maxdate=df.groupby('ts_code')['high'].transform('idxmax'))
   .pipe(lambda x: x[x.index >= x.maxdate])
   .pipe(lambda x: x[x.groupby('ts_code').cumcount() <= 1]))

#               ts_code     low    high    maxdate
# 2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0 2021-08-01
# 2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0 2021-08-01
# 2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0 2021-08-15
# 2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0 2021-08-22
# 2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0 2021-08-15
# 2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0 2021-08-22
```

---

### [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) alternative

You can also use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to index all events later than `group['high'].idxmax()`:

```
(df.groupby('ts_code')
   .apply(lambda group: group[group.index >= group['high'].idxmax()])
   .droplevel(0)
   .sort_values('ts_code'))

#               ts_code     low    high
# 2021-08-22  881105.TI  1656.0  1804.0
# 2021-08-15  885452.TI  2352.0  2459.0
# 2021-08-22  885452.TI  2329.0  2415.0
# 2021-08-01  885525.TI  7427.0  8552.0
# 2021-08-08  885525.TI  7300.0  7868.0
# 2021-08-15  885525.TI  7525.0  8236.0
# 2021-08-22  885525.TI  7400.0  8270.0
# 2021-08-22  885641.TI   691.0   720.0
```